# Strange behavior in Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, .net-core, thread-safety

I'm using Linq to create new threads in a loop and start them and then I Join the threads in the following loop. However, the first loop throws an exception that I'm very confused with before I can even join the threads. I'm getting an index out of range exception and i=3 even though the indexOfHeaders only has 3 elements (indexed 0,1,2). But what is even stranger is that I cant see the int numberOfThreads value when I break on exception in the debugger even though all the other local variables are visible. Is this because I'm using linq or the ternary operator incorrectly? None of this is reproducible when I step through the code slowly in the debugger.

```
private static void DecodeFileData(byte[] dataBuffer, UInt64 header, UInt64 trailer)
{
    byte[] headerBytesReceive = BitConverter.GetBytes(header);
    byte[] trailerBytesReceive = BitConverter.GetBytes(trailer);
    IEnumerable<int> indexOfHeaders = StartingIndex(dataBuffer, headerBytesReceive); //int indexOfHeader = Array.IndexOf(HundredKBBuffer, headerBytesReceive);
    // spawn up to 10 threads that look at the byte array for the right data
    SerialTest.DataFileWriter fileWriter = new SerialTest.DataFileWriter();
    int numberOfThreads = indexOfHeaders.Count() < 10 ? indexOfHeaders.Count() : 10;
    List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        Thread decodeThread = new Thread(() => DecodeDataAsync(dataBuffer, headerBytesReceive, trailerBytesReceive, indexOfHeaders.ElementAt(i), fileWriter));
        threadList.Add(decodeThread);
        decodeThread.Start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threadList.Count; i++)
        threadList.ElementAt(i).Join();
}

public static void DecodeDataAsync(byte[] dataBuffer, byte[] headerBytesReceive, byte[] trailerBytesReceive, int indexOfHeader, SerialTest.DataFileWriter fileWriter)
{ //lots of file writing and stuff that is irrelevent
```

DecodeFileData is called synchronously from another method.
DecodeDataAsync is asyncrounous as you can see from my posted code.

Comment: `DecodeDataAsync` doesn't become asynchronous just because you put `Async` at the end.

Comment: I understand. Maybe I should call it something else, I just named it that to remind myself to call it in a asynchronous manner. Is that not common practice?

Comment: Beware that using the loop variable in a LINQ expression will use the value i happes to have when this expression is executed. To avoid this, assign i to a local varable and use this.

Comment: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) (Wow, almost 10 years)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Question: I'm trying to visualize what is happening after reading that article. Wouldn't my current code just try to run each thread as indexOfHeaders.ElementAt(2) since 2 is the last element that collection. I'm still confused as to why the value of i went to 3 and why int numberOfThreads is not visible in the current context while the other variables are

Comment: @Goku - why do you think it would stop at 2? The operation of the `for` loop means that for it to terminate, it runs `i++` until it no longer satisfies `i < numberOfThreads`. That doesn't happen when `i` is equal to `2`, does it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think it does because there are 3 elements in indexOfHeaders. somehow, numberOfThreads is invisible in the context though, so maybe thats why it keeps going?


Also, in the article you posted, does the following comment mean that the problem you mentioned isn't relevant anymore? "Update: In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed. We return you now to our original article."

Comment: Yes, there are 3 elements, and that's what `numberOfThreads` will be equal to. So when `i` is `2`, `2<3` is true and so it runs through the loop body again. Then it runs `i++` again, and only at *that* point is `i < 3` false and so it exits the loop.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but we both know that a for loop checks the condition before it tries to run the body, so I=3 shouldn't ever make it into the indexOfHeaders.ElementAt(i), but somehow it does. and even stranger, I can't see the value of numberOfThreads

Comment: @Goku - it never runs the body of the loop when `i` equals `3`. That doesn't change the fact that *that variable got set to `3`*, and it's the value of *that variable* that is being used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Now I understand what you mean. I guess its weird that this happens since the aurther of the article you posted says "closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time". Will you post an answer so i can accept it? Your theory was actually exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things you need to be careful of:

Firstly, you are passing shared states:

```
byte[] dataBuffer, byte[] headerBytesReceive, byte[] trailerBytesReceive, int indexOfHeader, SerialTest.DataFileWriter fileWriter
```

Secondly, the variable `i` is *NOT* local to the thread.

```
DecodeDataAsync(dataBuffer, headerBytesReceive, trailerBytesReceive, indexOfHeaders.ElementAt(i), fileWriter));
```

Create a Wrapper function to copy it in a local variable and pass into the Thread.

Comment: Could you write a short example of what "copy it in a local variable of the Thread" means, just so I can understand what you mean. You don't have to use my code, just some example

Comment: @Goku - Depends on your requirements. Something like this: `void AddThreads(int i)
        {
            int idx = i;
            Thread decodeThread = new Thread(() => { Fun(idx) });
        }`